# codepen multiple product cards

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, codepen

I am trying to make 8 product cards in the same container and i am following this example :

`https://codepen.io/virgilpana/pen/RNYQwB`

But when i try to add a 2nd,3d,etc card the animation works only for the 1st card and the others appear as photos.

Is it possible to have the example functionality in every product?

The html code of the example:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<a id="view-code" href="https://codepen.io/virgilpana/pen/RNYQwB" target="_blank">VIEW CODE</a>

<div id="make-3D-space">
    <div id="product-card">
        <div id="product-front">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt.png" alt="" />
            <div class="image_overlay"></div>
            <div id="view_details">View details</div>
            <div class="stats">         
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <span class="product_price">$39</span>
                    <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>    
                    <p>Men's running shirt</p>                                            

                    <div class="product-options">
                    <strong>SIZES</strong>
                    <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                    <strong>COLORS</strong>
                    <div class="colors">
                        <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                </div>                         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="product-back">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div id="carousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large2.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large3.png" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="arrows-perspective">
                    <div class="carouselPrev">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                        <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carouselNext">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                        <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="flip-back">
                <div id="cy"></div>
                <div id="cx"></div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>  
</div>  

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there a fork of this codepen where you have added more cards?

Comment: https://codepen.io/arpamenos/pen/rwNayJ

Comment: your jQuery selector uses an id to add "animate" class. try changing that to a class instead of ID - because you should only have 1 id with the same name on the page

Comment: near top of your js the selector is $('#product-card').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('animate');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change all the id's to classes in the HTML CSS and JavaScript, and set (the now) `.product_card` to `position: relative;`, that should work!

Code Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 // Lift card and show stats on Mouseover
 $('.product-card').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('animate');
   $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');   
   }, function(){
   $(this).removeClass('animate');   
   $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
 }); 
 
 // Flip card to the back side
 $('.view_details').click(function(){  
  $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
  $('.product-card').addClass('flip-10');
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('.product-card').removeClass('flip-10').addClass('flip90').find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 80 , 1, function(){
    $('.product-front, .product-front div.shadow').hide();   
   });
  }, 50);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('.product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip190');
   $('.product-back').show().find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 90 , 0);
   setTimeout(function(){    
    $('.product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip180').find('div.shadow').hide();      
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('.product-card').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');   
     $('.cx, .cy').addClass('s1');
     setTimeout(function(){$('.cx, .cy').addClass('s2');}, 100);
     setTimeout(function(){$('.cx, .cy').addClass('s3');}, 200);    
     $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');    
    }, 100);
   }, 100);   
  }, 150);   
 });   
 
 // Flip card back to the front side
 $('.flip-back').click(function(){  
  
  $('.product-card').removeClass('flip180').addClass('flip190');
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('.product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip90');
 
   $('.product-back div.shadow').css('opacity', 0).fadeTo( 100 , 1, function(){
    $('.product-back, .product-back div.shadow').hide();
    $('.product-front, .product-front div.shadow').show();
   });
  }, 50);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('.product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip-10');
   $('.product-front div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 100 , 0);
   setTimeout(function(){      
    $('.product-front div.shadow').hide();
    $('.product-card').removeClass('flip-10').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');  
    $('.cx, .cy').removeClass('s1 s2 s3');   
   }, 100);   
  }, 150);   
  
 }); 

 
 /* ----  Image Gallery Carousel   ---- */
 
 var carousel = $('#carousel ul');
 var carouselSlideWidth = 335;
 var carouselWidth = 0; 
 var isAnimating = false;
 
 // building the width of the casousel
 $('#carousel li').each(function(){
  carouselWidth += carouselSlideWidth;
 });
 $(carousel).css('width', carouselWidth);
 
 // Load Next Image
 $('div.carouselNext').on('click', function(){
  var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
  var newLeft = currentLeft + carouselSlideWidth;
  if(newLeft == carouselWidth || isAnimating === true){return;}
  $('#carousel ul').css({'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
          "transition": "300ms ease-out"
        });
  isAnimating = true;
  setTimeout(function(){isAnimating = false;}, 300);   
 });
 
 // Load Previous Image
 $('div.carouselPrev').on('click', function(){
  var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
  var newLeft = currentLeft - carouselSlideWidth;
  if(newLeft < 0  || isAnimating === true){return;}
  $('#carousel ul').css({'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
          "transition": "300ms ease-out"
        });
     isAnimating = true;
  setTimeout(function(){isAnimating = false;}, 300);   
 });
});
```

```css
/* Generals resets and unimportant stuff */
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
body {
 background: #eaebec;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
}
.view-code{
  color:#48cfad; 
  font-size:14px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:640px; 
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-35px;
}
.view-code:hover{color:#34c29e;}

/* --- Product Card ---- */
.make-3D-space{
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800px;
    width:340px;
    height:500px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 5s;
    position:absolute;    
    top:80px;
    left:50%; 
    margin-left:-167px;
}
.product-front, .product-back{
 width:335px;
 height:500px;
 background:#fff;
 position:absolute;
 left:-5px;
 top:-5px;
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
}
.product-back{
 display:none;
 transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
.product-card.animate .product-back, .product-card.animate .product-front{
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
}
.product-card{
 width:325px;
 height:490px;
 position:relative;    
 top:10px;
 left:10px; 
 overflow:hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
            transition:  100ms ease-out;
}
div.product-card.flip-10{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( -10deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( -10deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( -10deg );
              transform: rotateY( -10deg );
      transition:  50ms ease-out;    
}
div.product-card.flip90{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 90deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 90deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 90deg );
              transform: rotateY( 90deg );
      transition:  100ms ease-in;    
}
div.product-card.flip190{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 190deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 190deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 190deg );
              transform: rotateY( 190deg );
      transition:  100ms ease-out;    
}
div.product-card.flip180{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
      transition:  150ms ease-out;    
}
.product-card.animate{
 top:5px;
 left:5px;
 width:335px;
 height:500px;
 box-shadow:0px 13px 21px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 -webkit-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
            transition:  100ms ease-out; 
}
.stats-container{
 background:#fff; 
 position:absolute;
 top:386px;
 left:0;
 width:265px;
 height:300px;
 padding:27px 35px 35px; 
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
.product-card.animate .stats-container{
 top:272px;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.stats-container .product_name{
 font-size:22px;
 color:#393c45; 
}
.stats-container p{
 font-size:16px;
 color:#b1b1b3; 
 padding:2px 0 20px 0;
}
.stats-container .product_price{
 float:right;
 color:#48cfad;
 font-size:22px;
 font-weight:600;
}
.image_overlay{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0; 
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:#48daa1;
 opacity:0; 
}
.product-card.animate .image_overlay{
 opacity:0.7; 
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.product-options{
 padding:2px 0 0;
}
.product-options strong{
 font-weight:700;
 color:#393c45;
 font-size:14px;
}
.product-options span{ 
 color:#969699;
 font-size:14px;
 display:block;
 margin-bottom:8px;
}
.view_details{ 
 position:absolute;
 top:112px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-85px; 
 border:2px solid #fff;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:19px;
 text-align:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:700;
 padding:10px 0;
 width:172px; 
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.view_details:hover{ 
 background:#fff;
 color:#48cfad;
 cursor:pointer;

}
.product-card.animate #view_details{
 opacity:1;
 width:152px;
 font-size:15px;
 margin-left:-75px;
 top:115px;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out;   
}
div.colors div{
 margin-top:3px;
 width:15px; 
 height:15px;  
 margin-right:5px;
 float:left;
}
div.colors div span{
 width:15px; 
 height:15px; 
 display:block;
 border-radius:50%;
}
div.colors div span:hover{
 width:17px;
 height:17px;
 margin:-1px 0 0 -1px;
}
div.c-blue span{background:#6e8cd5;}
div.c-red span{background:#f56060;}
div.c-green span{background:#44c28d;}
div.c-white span{
 background:#fff;
 width:14px;
 height:14px; 
 border:1px solid #e8e9eb;
}
div.shadow{
 width:335px;height:520px;
 opacity:0;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:3;
 display:none;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0.1),rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.1),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.1),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); 
}
.product-back div.shadow{
 z-index:10;
 opacity:1;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.1)); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.1)); 
}
.flip-back{
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 right:20px;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.cx, .cy{
 background:#d2d5dc;
 position:absolute;
 width:0px;
 top:15px;
 right:15px;
 height:3px;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
   transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.flip-back:hover .cx, .flip-back:hover .cy{
 background:#979ca7;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
   transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.cx.s1, .cy.s1{ 
 right:0; 
 width:30px; 
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.cy.s2{ 
 -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); 
 transform: rotate(50deg);   
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.cy.s3{ 
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
 transform: rotate(45deg);   
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.cx.s1{ 
 right:0; 
 width:30px; 
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.cx.s2{ 
 -ms-transform: rotate(140deg); 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg); 
 transform: rotate(140deg);   
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.cx.s3{ 
 -ms-transform: rotate(135deg); 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
 transform: rotate(135deg);   
 -webkit-transition: all 100ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
   transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.carousel{
 width:335px;
 height:500px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;

}
.carousel ul{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.carousel li{
 width:335px;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
.arrows-perspective{
 width:335px;
 height:55px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 218px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 5s;
 perspective: 335px;
}
.carouselPrev, .carouselNext{
 width: 50px;
 height: 55px;
 background: #ccc;
 position: absolute; 
 top:0;
 transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
 opacity:0.9;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.carouselNext{
 top:0;
 right: -26px;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY( -117deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( -117deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( -117deg );
              transform: rotateY( -117deg );
     transition: all 200ms ease-out;    

}
.carouselNext.visible{
  right:0;
  opacity:0.8;
  background: #efefef;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
              transform: rotateY( 0deg );
     transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.carouselPrev{  
 left:-26px;
 top:0;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY( 117deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 117deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 117deg );
              transform: rotateY( 117deg );
     transition: all 200ms ease-out; 

}
.carouselPrev.visible{
  left:0;
  opacity:0.8;
  background: #eee;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
              transform: rotateY( 0deg );
     transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.carousel .x, .carousel .y{
 height:2px;
 width:15px;
 background:#48cfad;
 position:absolute;
 top:31px;
 left:17px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
 transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
.carousel .x{
 -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);  
 -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
 transform: rotate(135deg);  
 top:21px;
}
.carousel .carouselNext .x{
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);  
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
 transform: rotate(45deg);  
}
.carousel .carouselNext .y{
 -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);  
 -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
 transform: rotate(135deg);  
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<a class="view-code" href="https://codepen.io/virgilpana/pen/RNYQwB" target="_blank">VIEW CODE</a>

<div class="make-3D-space">
    <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-front">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt.png" alt="" />
            <div class="image_overlay"></div>
            <div class="view_details">View details</div>
            <div class="stats">         
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <span class="product_price">$39</span>
                    <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>    
                    <p>Men's running shirt</p>                                            
                    
                    <div class="product-options">
                    <strong>SIZES</strong>
                    <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                    <strong>COLORS</strong>
                    <div class="colors">
                        <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                </div>                         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-back">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large2.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large3.png" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="arrows-perspective">
                    <div class="carouselPrev">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carouselNext">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flip-back">
             <div class="cy"></div>
                <div class="cx"></div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div> 
      <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-front">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt.png" alt="" />
            <div class="image_overlay"></div>
            <div class="view_details">View details</div>
            <div class="stats">         
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <span class="product_price">$39</span>
                    <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>    
                    <p>Men's running shirt</p>                                            
                    
                    <div class="product-options">
                    <strong>SIZES</strong>
                    <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                    <strong>COLORS</strong>
                    <div class="colors">
                        <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                </div>                         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-back">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large2.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large3.png" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="arrows-perspective">
                    <div class="carouselPrev">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carouselNext">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flip-back">
             <div class="cy"></div>
                <div class="cx"></div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(You should also use the latest version of JQuery, which is 3.2.1 not 1.11.2)

Comment: @Tonyp How's my answer?

Comment: Thank you very much your answer was helpfull but i am still facing some problems.I forgot to point that i want 8 individual product cards.
1st problem:when you click on the card for details all the product cards animate
2nd prob:the image carousel when you click for details doesnt work
3rd prob:when i place 2 cards on the same row the animations collide and this problem occurs because the css for animation force them to margin left 
All problems occur beacause there is no individuality on products cards but i feel so dumb with js and cant find the solution,any advise would be appreciated

Comment: @Tonyp Would you like me to help you via chat? Helping with those might take a while in the comments;

Comment: of cource my friend

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.. i cant talk to you

Comment: wait a minute,i will try to raise my reputation :p

Comment: you can help me here my friend if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145779/discussion-between-tonyp-and-james-douglas).